# How to solve this SQL syntax error in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I cant figure out how to solve this error. Please help me to resolve this!!

```
Dim Command As MySqlCommand
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim query As String

query = "INSERT into fishshop.recordsale (name,itemuse,description,price,qty,total,amount,change) values('" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "','" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "','" & TextBox10.Text & "')"
Command = New MySqlCommand(query, Moduleconn.conn)
reader = Command.ExecuteReader
MsgBox("transaction Successfuly Saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
conn.Close()
```

Image Of Error:

[image]

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  That will probably eliminate problems like you are now having.

Comment: Did you create the database? What datatypes are price,qty,total,amount,change? Do you really need to store amount and change?

Answer (score 1):

`change` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) for MySql.
You must use backticks around it to use it in the statement:

```
INSERT .....(..., `change`) VALUES .....
```

Also if the columns `change` and `total` are numeric, remove the `,` from the `TextBox`es text before you save them to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Keep you database objects local so you can control that they are closed and disposed. `Using...End` Using blocks take care of this for you even if there is an error.

Readers are for retrieving data. To Insert, Update or Delete data use `.ExecuteNonQuery`.

Use `Parameters` to avoid Sql Injection. This is very important because a malicious user can ruin your database. Parameters are just considered values by the server not executable code like Drop table which a user could enter in a textbox.

You must open a connection to use it. (Not so with a `DataAdapter` which opens and closes it for you) Always open the connection at the last possible second (right before the `.Execute`) and close it as soon as possible (always before the message box.)

```vb
Private Sub Insert()
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string."),
            Command As New MySqlCommand("Inset Into fishshop.recordsale (name,itemuse,description,price,qty,total) values(@name,@itemuse,@description,@price,@qty,@total)", conn)
        With Command.Parameters
            .Add("@name", MySqlDbType.String, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .Add("@itemuse", MySqlDbType.String, 50).Value = TextBox3.Text
            .Add("@description", MySqlDbType.String, 50).Value = TextBox5.Text
            .Add("@price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox4.Text)
            .Add("@qty", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox6.Text)
            .Add("@total", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox7.Text)
        End With
        conn.Open()
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 'closes and disposes connection and command
    MsgBox("transaction Successfuly Saved", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Message")
End Sub
```